# How to pass value from HTML page to use in python on postgresql query command

Tags: python, html, postgresql, sqlalchemy

First of all, I tried to get data from Postgresql, tried to show them into drop down list in HTML page, sent data from that drop down list which is selected one option to send back to python and use it to query data in Postgresql and finally showed the final result in HTML page again

I failed to list those list and send it back to python right now and I don't know much about Python, Jinja and Javascript.

This is my python code :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import operation

user = 'postgres'
pwd = '12345'
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = '5432'
dbname = 'test'

# engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}',pool_size=100, 
max_overflow=0)

engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{user}:{pwd}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}')
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"

@app.route('/testday', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def testday():

startday=request.form.get("startday")
endday=request.form.get("endday")
selectday=request.form.get("atday")

formulaselect = request.form.get("formula") <WANT THIS FROM HTML PAGE>
shiftvalue = request.form.get("shift") #WANT THIS FROM HTML PAGE

# Minimun day range in html date select
minday = db.execute('SELECT ("DATETIME"::timestamp::date) as "DATETIME" FROM "PL6_Daily" GROUP BY 
date("DATETIME") ORDER BY date("DATETIME") ASC limit 1 ')
minday = minday.first()[0] #DONE
# print(minday)
# Maximum day range in html date select
maxday = db.execute('SELECT ("DATETIME"::timestamp::date) as "DATETIME" FROM "PL6_Daily" GROUP BY 
date("DATETIME") ORDER BY date("DATETIME") DESC limit 1 ')
maxday = maxday.first()[0] #DONE
# print(maxday)

# List formula in drop down list
formula = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT "FORMULA" FROM "PL6_Daily"').fetchall() #DONE

# List shift in drop down list
shift = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT "SHIFT" FROM "PL6_Daily"').fetchall() #DONE

#Template use with data from html page, The one I want to resolve -->
performance = db.execute('SELECT DISTINCT "FORMULA","SHIFT", ("DATETIME"::timestamp::date) as 
 "DateTime", "PERFORMANCE" FROM "xxxx" WHERE ("DATETIME"::timestamp::date) = $$2020-01-03$$ 
<DONE> AND "FORMULA" = *data selected from html page* AND "SHIFT" = <data selected from html page> 
GROUP BY "FORMULA", date("DATETIME"),"SHIFT","PERFORMANCE" ORDER BY date("DATETIME") ',
{"shiftvalue":shiftvalue, "formula":formula, "selectday":selectday}) 


db.commit()
# db.close()

print(formulaselect)
print(shiftvalue)
print(selectday)


return render_template("testday.html",maxday=maxday,minday=minday,formula=formula,shift=shift)


if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my HTML page

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block title %}<title>TestDay</title>{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}

<div class="box">
        
      
<form action="{{ url_for('testday')}}" method="post">

     

<label for="formula">Select Formula :</label>

  

<select id="formulaselect" onchange="ddselect();">
    {%for i in formula%}
    
    <option value="{{i.FORMULA|e}}">{{i.FORMULA|e}}</option>

    {% endfor %}
   </select>
   
  <input type="text" id="formulavalue"/>

  <script>
    function ddselect()
    {
      var d = document.getElementById("formulaselect");
      var display = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
      document.getElementById("formulavalue").value = display;
      document.getElementById("formulavalue").value = 
      document.getElementById("formula").value;
    }
  </script>

<label for="atdat">Select Shift :</label>
          
        

<select id="shift" onchange="svselect();">

          {% for s in shift %}

          <option value="{{s['SHIFT']}}">{{s['SHIFT']}}</option>

          {% endfor %}

</select> 
    

<p id="shift"></p>
<input type="text" id="shiftvalue"/>

<script>
      function svselect()
      {
        var d = document.getElementById("shift");
        var display = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("shiftvalue").value = display;
        document.getElementById("shiftvalue").value = document.getElementById("shift").value;
      }
</script>

<label for="atday">Select Date :</label>
            
<input type="date" id="atday" name="atday" value={{minday}} min={{minday}} max= {{maxday}}>
          
<input type="submit">
            

</form>
</div>
```

I made 2 drop down lists which are formula name and shift and successfully show them in the list but I stuck at sending one of value inside drop down list back to python to query new data from Postgresql. Those two boxes next to each drop down list are just for showing the value that I selected.

[s1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqab8.png)

[s2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxLnK.png)

[S3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljHj2.png)

This is some of my data from postgresql :
[s4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PdXN.png)

and this is the result I want to show on HTML page (image from query in postgresql with acquired data):
[s5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVS72.png)

I'm sorry it's kinda messy since I'm really new to this.